# How to test Connect / Express middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing

Supposed I have a middleware for Connect and / or Express. What's the best way to unit test this middleware?

Of course, I can set up an http server in the unit tests, and load the middleware into this. But supposed that I want to test startup behavior, I need several http servers, which soon gets complicated and unclear (think of using a new port in each single test).

Is there a better way, or is testing it inside a real server the best one can come up with?

Comment: Use supertest.  Look at Express' tests; https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/test/req.xhr.js

Comment: Whoa, awesome, man :-)! This is *exactly* what I needed :-)! Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) does the job, as pointed out by [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) in the comments.